# Arrays and Objects In Prototypes - Not Treated as References

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reference

I have a prototype object in Javascript, when I initialise a new instance of the prototype and update properties in the prototype, it updates for all elements. I understand that arrays and objects are passed by reference and was wondering of a solution that would get you around this?

```
let Test = function () {}

Test.prototype = {
    array: [],
    add: function (value) {
        this.array.push(value)
    }
}

let test1 = new Test();
let test2 = new Test();

test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);

// Prints [1, 2]
console.log(test2.array);
```

One solution would be:

```
class Test {

    constructor() {
        this.array = []
    }

    add(value) {
        this.array.push(value)
    }
}

let test1 = new Test();
let test2 = new Test();

test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);

// Prints []
console.log(test2.array);
```

But I am not looking for an ES6 Approach, something more "native" javascript.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"But I am not looking for an ES6 Approach, something more "native" javascript."* `class` is entirely native JavaScript, and has been since June 2015. It's also supported, natively, but all up-to-date browsers, and transpilable for obsolete browsers.

Comment: Always keep in mind - JS does not do "classical" object orientation, and even when you're using the `class` keyword, you're not *really* creating a class. It's all just prototypes in disguise.

Comment: @Hecksa: They're really classes, in the computer science sense (encapsulation and inheritance). They're just not the same static compile-time construct that they are in languages like Java or C#. Classes implemented via prototypes are still classes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I was actually trying to say pretty much exactly what you just said (JS classes not being like people might know them from C# or Java), but I managed to not really say that at all. I'm certainly not trying to argue that the class keyword doesn't create a class (yes, despite that being exactly what I said). Thanks for the clarification, it's nice to have people around who can actually explain things to stop me from confusing everyone!

Answer (score 2):

That's the thing: they *are* treated as references.

When you do this:

```
Test.prototype = {
    array: [], // <- This creates a new array and it's being used in all instances
    add: function (value) {
        this.array.push(value)
    }
}
```

What you want is getting different array instances for different class instances. In that case, simply do `this.array = []` in your constructor:

```
let Test = function () { this.array = []; }
```

```js
let Test = function () { this.array = []; }

Test.prototype = {
    array: [],
    add: function (value) {
        this.array.push(value)
    }
}

let test1 = new Test();
let test2 = new Test();

test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);

console.log(test1.array);
// => [1, 2]

console.log(test2.array);
// => []
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize mutable members in the constructor, not in the prototype. If it's in the prototype, it will be shared between all instances:

```js
let Test = function () {
    this.array = [];
}

Test.prototype = {
    add: function (value) {
        this.array.push(value)
    }
}

let test1 = new Test();
let test2 = new Test();

test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);

console.log(test1.array);
console.log(test2.array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the array on the instance instead of on the prototype:

```
function Test() {
    this.array = [];
}

Test.prototype.add = function (value) {
    this.array.push(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that arrays and objects are passed by reference

No, they are not. But they're referenced by object references, which is an entirely different thing,<sup>1</sup> and is indeed the issue you're running into.

> and was wondering of a solution that would get you around this?

Do exactly what you did in the ES6 approach: Put it on the object itself, not the prototype:

```
let Test = function () {
    this.array = [];
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (All that the concepts "pass by reference" and "object reference" have in common is that they both use the word "reference." In the former, it's a reference to **a variable** [and a concept JavaScript doesn't have]. In the latter, it's a reference to an object.)